# Selecting dataframe rows based on values in other dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have following two dataframes:

df1:

```
name
abc
lmn
pqr
```

df2:

```
m_name  n_name  loc
abc     tyu     IND
bcd     abc     RSA
efg     poi     SL      
lmn     ert     AUS
nne     bnm     ENG
pqr     lmn     NZ
xyz     asd     BAN
```

I want to generate a new dataframe on following condition:

1. if df2.m_name==df1.name or df2.n_name==df1.name
2. eliminate duplicate rows

Following is desired output:

```
m_name  n_name  loc
abc     tyu     IND
bcd     abc     RSA
lmn     ert     AUS
pqr     lmn     NZ
```

Can I get any suggestions on how to achieve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df2)
  m_name n_name  loc
0    abc    tyu  IND
1    abc    tyu  IND
2    bcd    abc  RSA
3    efg    poi   SL
4    lmn    ert  AUS
5    nne    bnm  ENG
6    pqr    lmn   NZ
7    xyz    asd  BAN

df3 = df2.filter(like='name')
#another solution is filter columns by columns names in list
#df3 = df2[['m_name','n_name']]
df = df2[df3.isin(df1['name'].tolist()).any(axis=1)]
df = df.drop_duplicates(df3.columns)
print (df)
  m_name n_name  loc
0    abc    tyu  IND
2    bcd    abc  RSA
4    lmn    ert  AUS
6    pqr    lmn   NZ
```

**Details**:

Seelct all columns with `name` by [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
print (df2.filter(like='name'))
  m_name n_name
0    abc    tyu
1    abc    tyu
2    bcd    abc
3    efg    poi
4    lmn    ert
5    nne    bnm
6    pqr    lmn
7    xyz    asd
```

Compare by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
print (df2.filter(like='name').isin(df1['name'].tolist()))
   m_name  n_name
0    True   False
1    True   False
2   False    True
3   False   False
4    True   False
5   False   False
6    True    True
7   False   False
```

Get at least one `True` per row by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (df2.filter(like='name').isin(df1['name'].tolist()).any(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
7    False
dtype: bool
```

Filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df2[df2.filter(like='name').isin(df1['name'].tolist()).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
  m_name n_name  loc
0    abc    tyu  IND
1    abc    tyu  IND
2    bcd    abc  RSA
4    lmn    ert  AUS
6    pqr    lmn   NZ
```

And last remove duplicates [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) (If need remove dupes by all `name` columns add `subset` parameter)

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=df3.columns)
print (df)
  m_name n_name  loc
0    abc    tyu  IND
2    bcd    abc  RSA
4    lmn    ert  AUS
6    pqr    lmn   NZ
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
In [56]: df2[df2.m_name.isin(df1.name) | df2.n_name.isin(df1.name)]
Out[56]:
  m_name n_name  loc
0    abc    tyu  IND
1    bcd    abc  RSA
3    lmn    ert  AUS
5    pqr    lmn   NZ
```

Or using query

```
In [58]: df2.query('m_name in @df1.name or  n_name in @df1.name')
Out[58]:
  m_name n_name  loc
0    abc    tyu  IND
1    bcd    abc  RSA
3    lmn    ert  AUS
5    pqr    lmn   NZ
```